# Navigation width as body width

Tags: html, css, navigation, width

I have a navigation with 5 buttons: one active and four static. I'm using a `<ul>` because of one arrow for the active button. So the code looks like this:

```
    <ul>
        <li><div class="btn_active"><a href="#">active</a></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn_active_arrow"></div></li>
    </ul>
        <div class="seperator"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><div class="btn_static"><a href="#">static</a></div></li>
    </ul>
```

I have a body which has 95% width. How I can make the navigation be long as the body.

**Demo: www.dwnl.vjordanov.com/nav**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set percentage widths on everything.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation is inside body element, so just use:

`#navigation{width: 100%;}`

This will set navigation element width to 100% of it's parent element width.